# fullcalendar theme - "getIconClass of null"

Tags: fullcalendar, themes

At first I was having some error about my localeData in moment.js so I decided to update my moment and fullcalendar plugins. I am now using momentjs 2.19.1 and fullcalendar 3.6.1.

The error in moment.js is gone but now i'm getting an error in my console that traces back to the fullcalendar theme. The error says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getIconClass' of null
>
> at String. (fullcalendar.js:9410)

I am not using any themes (as far as I know), I tried loading in some themes with the new themeSystem but the error kept appearing. My fullCalendar configuration was and still is as followed:

```js
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    lang: "nl",
    header: {
        left: "prev,next today",
        center: "title",
        right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
    },
    defaultView: "month",
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    droppable: true,
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    businessHours: {
        start: "08:00",
        end: "17:00",
        dow: [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
});
```

Comment: The code you've shown does not generate any errors - [here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/x5zvf287/), using the same versions of Fullcalendar and Moment as you, and jQuery 3.2.1, which works fine.  What version of jQuery are you using?  The error must be coming from something other than what you've shown.  You say the error "traces back" - what is the full error?

Comment: I see, should've tested that myself. I'm running an older version of jquery because i'm using some other plugins as well, i'll play around with my jquery and other javascripts till it all starts working. Thanks for the Fiddle!